How do eradicated diseases make a comeback?
It's in the news this week that a case of polio was encountered in Gaza, the first case there in 25 years. The conflict between Israel and Hamas is blamed for reduced vaccination, so children are more susceptible to the disease.
But even if people are susceptible, how does the disease resurface? According to WHO, type 1 poliovirus remains in two countries, Pakistan and Afghanistan, but the child was infected with type 2, which was eradicated in 1999.
BBC wrote

According to the UN, Gaza, now in its 11th month of war, has not registered a polio case for 25 years, although type 2 poliovirus was detected in samples collected from the territory’s wastewater in June.

Where could the virus in the wastewater have come from?

One answer to the general question is "not so perma" frost. Smallpox appears to be a candidate to make a re-appearance.

Type 2 polio was still included in vaccines up until 2016. Recipients of the polio vaccine become immune, but in rare cases it's possible for vaccinated people to transmit disease to unvaccinated people, and for the virus to spread from there. Wild type 2 polio is eradicated; but some vaccine-derived cases still circulate. See also:
https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/30853/why-is-the-rate-of-circulating-vaccine-derived-poliovirus-disease-booming
There's a tough decision as far as when to stop distributing a particular strain via vaccine; on one hand, you keep open the potential of vaccine-derived spread. On the other hand, the protection against vaccine-derived spread is vaccination of everyone, since if everyone is vaccinated there cannot be spread.
Not every type of vaccine holds these risks, but the oral polio vaccine involves a live, attenuated virus, so that's one that causes a risk.

So the baby, who wasn't vaccinated, caught it from someone who was? They have the virus, but the vaccine prevented them from getting the disease?

@Barmar Not necessarily someone who was directly vaccinated, but someone who got it from someone who was (or someone who got it from someone who got it from someone who was).

But your point is that the virus is still around, because it's in the vaccines, but no one is symptomatic, because they've all been vaccinated? And they can then infect someone who isn't vaccinated?

@Barmar Other unvaccinated people can be symptomatic and spread it as well to other people who aren't vaccinated. That's why we keep vaccinating people. Polio also isn't always a severe disease even in people who are unvaccinated, so unvaccinated people who spread it to others may have brief/mild/no symptoms. The initial spread from someone vaccinated is an extremely rare event, but also many many people have been vaccinated against polio.

"Other unvaccinated people can be symptomatic". But the whole point of my question is that there have been no cases in 25 years -- there are no symptomatic people. Isn't that what we mean when we say a disease is eradicated?

@Barmar The only claim of eradication is of wild-origin type 2 based on a very long time passing with no observed cases of wild-origin type 2. We know there are vaccine-derived cases around. There is no funding to test every single person for polio, cases persist even if you're not aware of them.

Please see the link in my answer to the Medical Sciences Q&A and read the links in timeskull's answer like https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8393165/

OK, I hadn't considered the possibility that there were cases we didn't know about, since it's such a severe disease. Although it seems unlikely that none of the cases in 25 years would be diagnosed. Not to mention that a 10-month-old baby would have been exposed to one of them, they don't have very active social lives, especially in a war zone.

@Barmar The typical infection by poliovirus is not a severe disease, poliomyelitis is. Ordinarily polio replicates in the gut and causes at most a minor illness. Not something you'd even consider unusual. Occasionally, it gets into the blood and if so then it can possibly affect the CNS, where it causes chronic illness. The vast majority of people that are infected with poliovirus do not get poliomyelitis.

My question was about the disease, although I conflated it with the virus. I assume that when we say "So and so has polio" they're referring to the poliomyelitis disease. Is this analogous to the distinction between HIV (the virus) and AIDS (the disease it causes, which is now mitigated by various medicines)?

@Barmar A bit, but not really. I wouldn't bother with any analogies, just read about poliovirus, it's pretty straightforward and I've already described it: the virus ordinarily causes an infection in the gut, and spreads fecal-oral. Sometimes, it spreads to the blood. Sometimes when it spreads to the blood, it also makes it to the CNS and causes poliomyelitis. The people who that happens to definitely know about it. The people who have just the simple gut infection almost certainly do not know about it. It's all the same virus, so it can spread around without being known.

‘Some vaccine derived cases still circulate’ I’m far from an expert on this, but my understanding is that as of right now, these actually account for almost all reported cases of paralytic poliomyelitis. I believe the official numbers from the WHO for 2023 were 12 reported cases from WPV compared to 524 from cVDPV.

@AustinHemmelgarn Yes, the linked post to Medical Sciences discusses this. For Type 2, it's all of the cases.

@Barmar: Over 99% of polio infections are either completely asymptomatic or indistinguishable from those caused by other gastrointestinal virusses, even for the wild-type virus (and even-more-so with cVDPV).

When they say this is the first case in 25 years, do you think they're being imprecise and referring to poliomyelitis, not polio in general? When millions of children were dying from polio, was that actually poliomyelitis?

I always assumed they were the same thing, just as "flu" is short for "influenza".

@Barmar Usually "polio" as a disease is short for poliomyelitis. We don't really have a short name for the normal, non-poliomyelitis version of the infection because, well, it's so minor.

BTW, I did hear on the news today something like "only 1 in 1,000 cases are symptomatic, so it's probably widespread in Gaza."
